# How to reset control after ScaleTransform animation

Tags: c#, animation, uwp, storyboard, windows-10-universal

I am working on a Windows 10 universal application targeting PC. I want to run an animation repeatedly (not in a "RepeatBehaviour" loop, but run it again after something else happens), but I am struggling with resetting the animated control AFTER animation completes.

One of the animations in a storyboard is TranslateTransform. After it completes, I can re-position the control using Canvas.SetLeft and Canvas.SetTop in code. However, after I "disappear" a control using ScaleTransform animation the control remains invisible and I cannot make it visible again. Changing control Height and Width does nothing.

Using AutoReverse in XAML does resolve the issue, but I do not want this to be visible to the user. The control is supposed to "disappear". I want to reset the control in code before the next run, behind the scenes.

My Storyboard and the Border control which I am animating are shown below. This works fine the first time. The image flies across the screen with some rotation and then disappears. Second time the image is invisible until the scale transform runs again.

I tried adding another ScaleTransform animation before the first key frame, to scale from 0 to 1 quickly (I tried duration of "0" or "0.1") but that breaks the whole thing for some reason.

I wonder if RenderTransformOrigin has something to do with this, but am unsure how to use it with TransformGroup. So it is set to (0.5,0.5) to center the rotation.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
 <Storyboard x:Name="myStoryboard">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                        Storyboard.TargetName="myImage"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)"
                        EnableDependentAnimation="False">
                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="MyTopSpline"   KeyTime="0:0:1.9"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                        Storyboard.TargetName="myImage"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)"
                        EnableDependentAnimation="False"">
                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="MyLeftSpline" KeyTime="0:0:1.9"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myImage" 
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(RotateTransform.Angle)" 
                             From="0" To="360" BeginTime="0:0:1.0" Duration="0:0:1.9" />

                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myImage"
                                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" 
                             From="1" To="0" BeginTime="0:0:1.9" Duration="0:0:0.9" />
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myImage"
                                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" 
                             From="1" To="0" BeginTime="0:0:1.9" Duration="0:0:0.9"  />


</Storyboard>

  <Border Name="myImage"  Height="244" Width="244" Canvas.Left="200" Canvas.Top="100" Visibility="Collapsed" 
RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5">
        <Border.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
                </TransformGroup>
         </Border.RenderTransform>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this line of code to StoryBoard completed event resolved the issue:

```
MyStoryboard.Stop();
```

Comment: I got a feeling there's something else wrong in your code. Having to call this doesn't make any sense.

Comment: This is now raised as a bug to MS: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3135070/scaletransform-animation-does-not-reset-after-storyboard-completes

Comment: awesome! I will keep an eye on it.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's clean up your code a bit. Instead of using a `TransformGroup`, you should use a composite transform object called `CompositeTransform` as it's a lot easier to work with. Don't forget to name it too.

```
<Border.RenderTransform>
    <CompositeTransform x:Name="myImageTransform" />
</Border.RenderTransform>
```

So now your `Storyboard` should look like the following. Note that I have added a `myStoryboard_Completed` handler to it.

```
<Storyboard x:Name="myStoryboard"
            Completed="myStoryboard_Completed">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="myImage"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)">
        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="MyTopSpline" KeyTime="0:0:1.9" />
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="myImage"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)">
        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="MyLeftSpline" KeyTime="0:0:1.9" />
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myImage"
                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.Rotation)"
                     From="0"
                     To="360"
                     BeginTime="0:0:1.0"
                     Duration="0:0:1.9" />

    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myImage"
                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleX)"
                     From="1"
                     To="0"
                     BeginTime="0:0:1.9"
                     Duration="0:0:0.9" />
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myImage"
                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleY)"
                     From="1"
                     To="0"
                     BeginTime="0:0:1.9"
                     Duration="0:0:0.9" />
</Storyboard>
```

Inside this handler, all you need to do is to reset all the transform attributes and canvas offsets.

```
private void myStoryboard_Completed(object sender, object e)
{
    myImage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

    Canvas.SetTop(myImage, 100);
    Canvas.SetLeft(myImage, 200);

    myImageTransform.Rotation = 0;
    myImageTransform.ScaleX = myImageTransform.ScaleY = 1;
}
```

### But here is a better way.

Instead of doing some of the stuff in code behind, why not wrap all the logic inside the same `Storyboard`? All you need is to use `DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames` to define **both start and end values** for each of your animations.

```
<Storyboard x:Name="myStoryboard">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="myImage"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)">
        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="100" />
        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="MyTopSpline" KeyTime="0:0:1.9" Value="100" />
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="myImage"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)">
        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="200" />
        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="MyLeftSpline" KeyTime="0:0:1.9" Value="200" />
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.Rotation)"
                                   Storyboard.TargetName="myImage">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0" />
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.9" Value="360" />
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleX)"
                                   Storyboard.TargetName="myImage">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1" />
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.9" Value="1" />
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.8" Value="0" />
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleY)"
                                   Storyboard.TargetName="myImage">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1" />
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.9" Value="1" />
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.8" Value="0" />
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                   Storyboard.TargetName="myImage">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for that. CompositeTransform is sure easier to work with than the TransformGroup, but unfortunately it does NOT resolve the problem. The image is still invisible until the next time scale transform runs (the code in completed event does run). It seems that just changing the ScaleX and ScaleY values does not actually reset the control. Also, I cannot do everything in XAML as a lot of values are calculated at run time. I think I need to force the object to re-scale to X=Y=1 but don't know how...

Comment: I'd like to see a live demo of this issue 'cause the above code does work in my project. BTW did you set the `Visibility` back to `Visible` in the callback?

Comment: Actually there's an easy way to debug your issue. Have you tried Live Visual Tree before? You can inspect `myImage` there and in the Live Property Explorer, you can then find all the transformation, Visibility, Canvas.Left values and modify them directly there, then you should be able to work out which one is miscalculated.

Comment: it's not the visibility as the control appears when scale transformation runs. once I scale it to zero it doesn't recover until the next scale transform. I'll try the visual tree for troubleshooting tonight...

Comment: by the way, if I use AutoRestore in scale transformation, it fixes the problem. I just don't want user to see it...

Comment: Clearly some of your code sets the scale or offset that makes it look invisible... But without seeing the code, I can't really say what is wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145526/discussion-between-under-and-justin-xl).